# Run a method of base class automatically after constructor of a child instance

Tags: python

I want a way to run `func_z` after `ChildClass constructor` automatically.

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("BaseClass constructor")
        self.func_z()

    def func_z(self):
        print("BaseClass func_z")

class ChildClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("ChildClass constructor")
```

so it would print

```
BaseClass constructor
ChildClass constructor
BaseClass func_z
```

Of course the whole point is not to put `self.func_z()` manually after `print("ChildClass constructor")`.

I don't want to redefine or override `func_z` in the child class.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `self.func_z()` if that's what you want to do?

Comment: its about regularization in class info
assume I would inherent the child class for many times so some class properties need to be regulated in case the in the inheritance I forget to do sth
it has also more use cases, like in base class definition I cant define sth because it needs the properties of child class.
if u are curious I can give u more info.

Comment: suppose I would put it available so other users will always inherent from this class. oddly this seems to has lots of use cases but I have not encountered with the solution to this.

Comment: thanks @mkrieger1 of maybe anyone else to provided the search result